# What IDEone Execution time represents

Tags: c++, time, execution

I'm using IDEone and i'm wondering what the "time" value represent after execution.

The code i'm executing is a simple hello world in which I have a fork() call and a sleep(1) which is a 1 second sleep and the time value return from IDEone is 0.01...

```
   result: Success      time: 0.01s    memory: 2680 kB     returned value: 0
```

Any explenation on what time represent? There isn't much in their FAQ.

Would it be right to think that the time represent the CPU-Time of the execution?

Comment: Can you post the link to the ideone code pls?

Comment: http://ideone.com/1nmLiC

Comment: Yeah... That's what i'm thinking too... Thanks...

Comment: [This IDEone](http://ideone.com/dT9clW) seems to indicate that it is probably CPU time rather than actual time.